# What is RAW and STG and Consumption in Project

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

In My project sources are FlatFile and we are loading data into HANA DB.

1st Phase : we are loading FlatFiles data into Target FlatFile by applying some business logics like ltrim,rtrim,round, substring
2nd Phase :  we are taking the generated Target File as a source and loading this data to Raw Tables(DB2). here also we are applying Trim and round functions with some date passing to tgt
3rd Phase : The data loaded in DB2 again processed to STG tables in same database. (no logics on column data)

My question is why we are loading data into RAW and STG. can't we directly load data into STG ?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your architecture, it looks like this -

```
Flat file -expr--> Flat File -->raw(DB2) --trim, date trim/filter --> STG(DB2)
```

Now, for rwa to stg, its clear that your structure is bringing all data into raw layer first and then applying some date logic etc to load into stg layer. RAW is used a pre stage here and contains all data. STG will be loaded incrementally(i am assuming). So this is an idea lot of DW uses. This way, stg takes less time to load and if you want all data you have raw layer table.
Yes, you can directly load into stg but then the flexibility of running incremental , holding all data in raw will be lost. Its upto you or your design, you can avoind raw as well, informatica can run incremental easily.

End of the day, someone made it with some logic in mind. If you see better performance and business okays it, please go for it.